# sum 4th field data between the pattern

Tags: scripting

suppose my data is :

*dnet *1234 1.2

1 port *12 2.3

3 port1 *34 0.2

7 *15 0.1

*dnet *234 0.2

2 *12 0.1

4 *123 *234 1.2

fields are separated by space.

In this I want to get the sum of 4th fields of data present inside each *dnet. Some fields have 4th field data some has not. I want 4th field sum value for each *dnet seperate.

I tried using awk but could not get. It will be thankful if someone helps.

the output for above will look like

*dnet *1234 1.2 2.5

*dnet *234 0.2 1.2

Comment: `awk 'function p(){if(n){print n,s;n=s=0}} $1=="*dnet"{p();n=$0;next} $4{s+=$4} END{p()}' data`

Comment: Thank you so much buddy, This works. you are great!

Comment: Can you please explain the code once. It will be helpful

Answer (score 1):

Commented, slightly simplified, version of the comment...

```
awk '
    # look for header line
    $1=="*dnet" {
        # print any previously calculated sum
        if (header) print header, sum

        # reset sum for next block of lines
        sum = 0

        # save new header line
        header = $0

        # skip remaining actions
        next
    }

    # if we get here, we know this is not a header line
    # if there is a 4th field, add it to the sum
    $4 {
        sum += $4
    }

    END {
        # print the final sum
        if (header) print header, sum
    }
' datafile
```